# UIAlertView crash on click - Using ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uialertview

I have a class called `FlightRecorder` and `BookmarkTableViewController`. Now, I am presenting the `BookmarkTableViewController`. And now I am dismissing that view controller. Here is what the code looks like:

```
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

    FlightRecorder *fl = [[FlightRecorder alloc] init];
    [fl endBookmarkProcessWithBookmarkCollection: dict];

    }
```

This is getting called after selection of a table view cell. So, `FlightRecorder` has a method called `endBookmarkProcessWithBookmarkCollection:` where you pass on an `NSDictionary` which looks like this:

```
- (void)endBookmarkProcessWithBookmarkCollection: (NSDictionary *)dict {

NSString *compiledText = @"Random Airline";

NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"\nMiles: %.2f\nFlight: %@\nDate: %@", [[dict objectForKey: @"miles"] floatValue], compiledText, [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"tempD"]];

self.bkBookmarkAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Confirmation" message:string delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Add", nil];

[bkBookmarkAlertView show];

}
```

So as you can see, I use the dictionary and some other variables to piece together the message of an alert view! The alert view has two buttons, Cancel and Add. But the problem is that when you press either of them, they both crash, and the `clickedButtonAtIndex:` delegate method is not called. I have not had this experience with any other alert views in the exact same view controller.

I looked at some other questions of similar manner, but they're solutions were using ARC. Bottomline they said that `self`, the delegate of the alert view, is nil or overreleased or something like that. So I thought, maybe that method is getting called before the view loads, even though it is called on apparent completion (the completion block in `BookmarksTableViewController`).

So I decided to put `NSLog`'s in both `viewDidLoad` and `endBookmarkProcessWithBookmarkCollection:`, but `viewDidLoad` **is** getting called first, so I am not sure where the problem is.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Edit: turned comment into answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That block has finished executing and f1 has gone out of scope and been deallocated well before you tap the buttons. I'm not familiar with the architecture of your app but you'll need to find an owner for that object while waiting for the tap.

Comment: Thank you, making the variable static and allocating it before the completion block worked